# Dynamic start date from specific column in a table (sysdate)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-sql, sysdate

I am pretty new in this field, trying to learn slowly so please be patient with me :)

My database contains a table called t_usage_interval. In this table there is a column name ID_Interval. Each month a new random 10 digit number is created in this column.

[This is the query I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ4D5.png)

I would like to find out if there is a way to pull the latest interval by using column name DT_START with SYSDATE option? I guess it would be a dynamic query search from a sysdate to display the latest ID_Interval?

Thank you,
A

Comment: Your question is not clear. In each new month whether a new row is inserted or existing row updated? When DT_START or DT_END inserted or updated?

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output with description in text format. Also please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I understood the question.

A *straightforward* query returns row(s) whose `dt_start` is the first in that table that is lower or equal to sysdate (you might also use `trunc(sysdate)`, if you don't care about time component). Drawback of this query is that it scans `t_usage_Interval` table twice.

```
select *
from t_usage_interval a
where a.dt_start = (select max(b.dt_start)
                    from t_usage_interval b
                    where b.dt_start <= sysdate
                   );
```

Somewhat less *intuitive* option is to "rank" rows (whose `dt_start` is lower than sysdate) by `dt_start`, and then return row(s) that rank the "highest". This option scans the table only once, so it should perform better.

```
with temp as
  (select a.*,
     rank() over (order by a.dt_start desc) rn
   from t_usage_interval a
   where a.dt_start <= sysdate
  )
select t.*
from temp t
where t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I needed :)

Comment: You're wekcome.